# How to create applications sending HTTP-GET/POST?

Tags: c++, html

I'm trying to write an application what is communicating with a web-server.
I've created a server, set it as a proxy, and I get this message:

```
GET http://SOMETHING.SG/ HTTP/1.1
Host: SOMETHING
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: [...SOMETHING...]
Connection: keep-alive
```

1) What are these lines saying? (eg. Gecko)

2) Is it possible to create a GET message without some of these lines?

3) Is there something that changes across the time, and won't work?

4) Is it possible to create a C++ built-in library what does it for me?

5-8) The same questions with HTTP-POST

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)

Comment: Sounds like you need to read [the HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html).

Comment: Sorry for the question, I accidentally searched for, and written HTML-GET instead of HTTP-GET. If I had known that, I'd have found the answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) does that. It contains HTTP client that allows you to do GET/POST requests programmatically.

Comment: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html

Comment: can you provide how import libcurl latest vestion in visual studio 2015 ? if you can't your response not solve my problem

Answer (score 4):

That's is a HTTP/1.1 GET request for `http://index.hu/`. To fully understand the entire request, you should probably read [the HTTP/1.1 specification (RFC2616)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html).

But to summarise quickly:

- *Host* - The host of the resource being requested
- *User-Agent* - A string that describes the user agent being used to access the resource. This user agent suggests you were using Firefox. Firefox's layout engine is called Gecko.
- *Accept* - Gives the preferred mime types of the requested resource. In this case, the requester would like to receive the resource as HTML.
- *Accept-Language* - Gives the preferred language of the requested resource.
- *Accept-Encoding* - Gives the preferred encodings of the requested resource.
- *Cookie* - An extension header defined by [RFC2109](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt) for using cookies.
- *Connection* - Specifies options for the connection. In this case, `keep-alive` requests a persistent connection.

Not all of these headers are required and there are many more that you might want to use. The descriptions of all headers are given in the specification.

There are many C++ libraries which can construct and send HTTP requests for you. A popular one is [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/). There's also [an official tutorial](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html).